# I have got this blue screen with stopcode "irql not less or equal". What do I do now?

Tags: windows-10, bsod

Laptop model: HP pavilion g6 2230tx

Operating System: Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB 2016, 64 bit.

I have got this message twice, once after starting hwinfo, and another after switching the graphic setting of onenote.exe from *power saving* to *high performance*, in the AMD catalyst control centre. Laptop restarted, but I don't want to leave this here, if it suggesting me to do something. What optimal do I do now, something or nothing? If there is anything to be done, what is that? :)

[image]

Comment: [analyze the dmps with windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) or share the dmp files from C:\windows\minidump if you can't use windbg

Comment: As a 5 minute exercise, you could upload the mini-dump here: http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm?name=Analyze , the stack presented will be of most interest to see the modules and then you may want to consider the version of these, i.e. are they up to date.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Now I have moved to Linux. I could have had posted the minidump file, to help others with the same problem, but it has been completely erased. I have fan problem, which I am discussing here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389996/how-to-control-fan-speed-in-linux-running-hp-laptop?noredirect=1#comment694851_389996

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I noticed that this is happening after hibernation. It now seems to have helped me to increase the size of hiberfil.sys from default 75% to 100%. Run as an adm from cmd:

```
powercfg -h -size 100%
```